How to get a json argument in cli command using typer in python?
I'm using **typer ** in python to create a cli command that takes 2 parameters: a dict/json argument and a json file path.
The command should append the json argument to the received json file.
But typer accepts the string without the " " that surround {"key":"value"}
and so json_to_add=json.loads(argument) fails to convert the string to dict.
In terminal the executed command is (my filename is main.py) : python main.py '{"Name": "Lily"}' "D:\students.json" 
and the '{"Name": "Lily"}' received as {Name : Lily}
How can typer get str and leave the quotes needed for json format?
The code is:
import typer
import json

app = typer.Typer()


@app.command()
def append(argument: str, path: str):
    print(type(argument))
    print(argument)
    try:
        # Parse the JSON-formatted string into a Python dictionary
        json_to_add = json.loads(argument)
        print(type(json_to_add))
    except:
        typer.echo(f"error: the input {argument} is not a valid json argument!")
        raise typer.Exit(1)

    try:
        with open(path, "r") as file:
            # Load existing JSON data from the file
            json.dump(json_to_add, file)
    except:
        FileNotFoundError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()

The output for execute python main.py '{"Name": "Lily"}' "D:\students.json"  is:
enter image description here

Try: python main.py '{\"Name\": \"Lily\"}' "D:\students.json" 

I formatted your code to make it easier to read, your indentation was inconsistent as well as using only a single space mostly. Please stick the the python convention of 4 spaces for indentation

anyway, this seems to be more of a bash (or whatever shell you are using) issue. Typer isn't modifying the string it recieves.

@juanpa.arrivillaga
Thanks it worked. But is there a way to insert simple JSON and it will still work? I want to create a simple and user-friendly cli command. the syntax with the \ is a bit too complicated.

@juanpa.arrivillaga
By the way, typer did receive the string in a different way - without any quotes.
The output for
python main.py '{"Name": "Lily"}' "D:\students.json"
is
<class 'str'> {Name: Lily} error: the input {Name: Lily} is not a valid json argument!

@Tamar.M I didn't provide that answer, but I am almost certain that fundamentally your issue is shell-specific, it isn't really a python question at all. For example, in my bash shell, the single quotes work fine for this. What shell are you using? what does echo $SHELL in your terminal give you?

@Tamar.M but that isn't typer. At least, I am almost certain it isn't, but let's try to figure it out, what does python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv)' '{"a":1}' give you?

Oh, just realized you were on Windows! What shell are you using, powershell? or command shell? But regardless, what does the above give you when you run it in a terminal, i.e. python -c 'import sys; print(sys.argv)' '{"a":1}' 

so I am not a windows user, but from some googling, if you are using command shell, there is no great way to use a raw string without escaping double quotes (since double quotes are used to create a raw string). Again, this is a shell issue. Python receives the string from the shell, it doesn't modify the string, and it passes it on to typer, which also doesn't modify the string
